# result sum does not match

Tags: mysql, sum

I have a table schema like this.

```
mysql> desc material_out;

+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| barcode     | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| name        | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| qty         | double       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| unit        | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| num_letter  | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date        | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| destination | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc material_in;

+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| barcode     | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| name        | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| qty         | double       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| unit        | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| num_letter  | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date        | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| destination | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc goods;

+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| barcode     | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| name        | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| unit        | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| category    | varchar(25)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| first_stok  | double    )  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In table material_out I have data of 10,000 rows. and has as many as 350 types of barcodes. In table material_in I have data around 15,000 rows. and has as many as 200 types of barcodes.

**my query is like this**

```
SELECT br.barcode,
    COALESCE(tNEW.total_out,0) AS total_out, COALESCE(tNEW.total_in,0) as total_in,
    COALESCE(tNEW.total_in,0)-COALESCE(tNEW.total_out,0) AS result,
    COALESCE(tOLD.total_out,0) AS total_out_old, COALESCE(tOLD.total_in,0) AS total_in_old
FROM (
SELECT barcode from goods where category=1
) as br
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT goods.barcode,
        COALESCE(SUM(tOUT.qty),0) AS total_out,
        COALESCE(SUM(tIN.qty),0) AS total_in
    FROM goods
    LEFT JOIN material_out AS tOUT ON tOUT.barcode=goods.barcode
    LEFT JOIN material_in AS tIN ON tIN.barcode=goods.barcode
    WHERE goods.category=1
        AND tOUT.date >='2013-05-01' AND tOUT.date <='2013-08-31'
        AND tIN.date >= '2013-05-01' AND tIN.date <= '2013-08-31'
    GROUP BY goods.barcode
) AS tNEW ON tNEW.barcode=br.barcode
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT goods.barcode,
        SUM(tOUT.qty) AS total_out,
        SUM(tIN.qty) AS total_in
    FROM goods
    LEFT JOIN material_out AS tOUT ON tOUT.barcode=goods.barcode
    LEFT JOIN material_in AS tIN ON tIN.kode=goods.barcode
    WHERE goods.category=1
        AND tOUT.date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-04-31'
        AND tIN.date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-04-31'
    GROUP BY goods.barcode
) AS tOLD ON tOLD.barcode=br.barcode
```

I have used a query like that. the result is going well. but when I try to enter new data. I then re-query of your display. but the results are not in accordance with the entered data. for example, when I enter a query from you. The following results

```
+--------------+-----------+----------+------------+---------------+-------------------+
|    barcode   | total_out | total_in | result     | total_out_old | total_in_old      |
+--------------+-----------+----------+------------+---------------+-------------------+
| TNWET021     |      6195 |    15000 |       8805 |         20085 |             46200 |
| TNWET020     |      3420 |     7650 |       4230 |          4860 |             23925 |
| TNWET019     |      8370 |    25200 |      16830 |         11610 |             47175 |
| TNWET018     |     18690 |    44100 |      25410 |         13800 |             54150 |
| TNWET017     |      1140 |     3750 |       2610 |          3690 |             16200 |
| TNWET016     |     19500 |    56100 |      36600 |         31725 |            111300 |
| TNWET015     |      5145 |    18150 |      13005 |          6510 |             23400 |
| TNWET014     |     33300 |    65250 |      31950 |         96300 |            262500 |
| TNWET013     |      1170 |     5625 |       4455 |          3690 |             13200 |
| TNWET012     |       720 |     2700 |       1980 |          3870 |             13800 |
| TNWET011     |         0 |        0 |          0 |           180 |               450 |
| TNWET010     |         0 |        0 |          0 |           405 |              1125 |
| TNWET009     |         0 |        0 |          0 |             0 |                 0 |
```

When I do a manual summation and results like this.

```
mysql> select sum(qty) from material_in where barcode='TNWET021' and date BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-08-31';
+-------------+
|   sum(qty)  |
+-------------+
|         750 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select sum(qty) from material_in where barcode='TNWET020' and date BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-08-31';
+-------------+
|   sum(qty)  |
+-------------+
|         450 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why the results can be very much different, when the data is very vital for reporting. Please help me.

I used this earlier but it took a long time to execute. maybe you can help to summarize this query to quickly executed

```
SELECT COALESCE(tIN.total_in,0) + COALESCE(production.total_prod,0) AS incoming, COALESCE(tOUT.total_out,0) AS expenditure,br.barcode as barcode, br.name,br.initial_stock,br.unit,COALESCE(adj.total,0) AS adjusment,COALESCE(tIN.total_in,0) + COALESCE(production.total_prod,0) + COALESCE(adj.total,0) + COALESCE(br.intial_stock,0) - COALESCE(tOUT.total_out,0) as final_stok,so.stock_opname from (
select barcode,name,initial_stock,unit from barang where category=1
) as br
LEFT JOIN (
select (select sum(qty) from material_out where date >= '2013-05-01' AND date <='2013-08-31' and barcode=a.barcode) as total_out,a.barcode from material_out a group by a.barcode
) as tOUT
ON tOUT.barcode=br.barcode
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT(
SELECT SUM(qty) FROM adjusment
WHERE status = '+' AND date >= '2013-05-01' AND date <= '2013-08-31'
) - (
SELECT SUM(qty) FROM adjusment
WHERE status = '-' AND date >= '2013-05-01' AND date <= '2013-08-31'
) AS total,barcode FROM adjusment
GROUP BY barcode
) AS adj
ON br.barcode = adj.barcode
LEFT JOIN (
select (select sum(qty) from material_in where date >= '2013-05-01' AND date <='2013-08-31' and barcode=a.barcode) as total_in,a.barcode,a.nama from material_in a group by a.barcode
) as tIN
ON br.barcode=tIN.barcode
LEFT JOIN (
select (select sum(qty) from view_production where date >= '$start' AND date <='$end' and kode=a.kode) as total_prod,a.barcode from view_production a group by a.barcode
) as production
ON br.barcode=production.barcode

LEFT JOIN (
select(select sum(qty) from stock_opname where date >= '2013-04-01' AND date <= '2013-05-31' AND barcode=a.barcode) as stok_opname,a.barcode from pencacahan a group by a.barcode
) as so
ON br.barcode=so.barcode
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `tIN.kode=goods.barcode` you should write `tIN.barcode=goods.barcode`.

Can you try this?

```
SELECT goods.barcode,
    tOUT.qty,
    tIN.qty
FROM goods
LEFT JOIN material_out AS tOUT ON tOUT.barcode=goods.barcode
LEFT JOIN material_in AS tIN ON tIN.barcode=goods.barcode
WHERE goods.category=1
    AND tOUT.date >='2013-05-01' AND tOUT.date <='2013-08-31'
    AND tIN.date >= '2013-05-01' AND tIN.date <= '2013-08-31'
```

I have a hypothesis. (See in the comments.)
You will see the same qty numbers more times than you expected.

If I am right then you should aggregate first all partial result, and join them later.

Comment: I investigated the first subquery. Probably There are more record for the same goods. If for example there are 2 matching records in the material_in, and 2 in the material_out, then they will multiply each other. You can verify this if you run the first big subquery without grouping/aggregation. (I modify the answer.)

Comment: query of you remains the same, the result is invalid. I've changed my query is valid but it took a long time to execute the query